# Customising specific fields in Django Admin change form

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a couple of fields in my model that to which I wish to add a link that will allow the user to search for names/files (external from the application's database).

So what I would like is:

> Field name: [text box] - LINK

Is there a straightforward django way of achieving this?

Cheers.

Comment: i don't follow. could you explain in some more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the widget that the form field uses to display the models information. You basically add some html after the input to link to where you want.

Here's some code I put together to create a widget that displays how many characters are left for a CharacterField so it's similar to what you are looking to do:

https://github.com/pastylegs/django-widget-charsleft/blob/master/widget_charsleft/widgets.py